# react native how to use fast fourier Transform with my data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, fft

My team want to evaluate and check micro current through a sensor and bluetooth to react-native app when someone workout.

I have a list of voltage powers from workout.

example) list = [1023,300,200,500,...]

Xaxis is index(This will change to time).

Yaxis is voltage.

My Maximum size is 1023(max is 1024-1)

[image]

I want to make this data into frequency and amplitude graph(linear graph that I can know I am doing good on my workout)

My mentor said me to use the fast fourier transform.
But it doesn't matter if I use different algorithm or just integral to make the list data to frequency and amplitude  linear graph.

[image]

There was no react-native library, I have searched some npm library such as fft-js, fft.js, dsp.js

from here https://npm.io/search/keyword%3Afft/1

But I don't know how to use them. I really don't understand where to put my data when I use the library.

for instance, https://npm.io/package/fft.js

```
const FFT = require('fft.js');
const f = new FFT(4096);
// what is the size meaning? It means my voltage maximum height? which is 1024?
const input = new Array(4096);
input.fill(0);
const out = f.createComplexArray();

//where to put my data to realInput variable??
const realInput = new Array(f.size);
f.realTransform(out, realInput);
```

If there is an example GitHub code, it would be really helpful..
If someone made it, would you please help me?

Comment: until you master this I suggest you start by using a known input say a sinusoidal curve of known frequency maybe 1000 Hertz then feed this array into your FFT call which will return back a new array then from this new array resolve out the magnitude for each array element to confirm you get a spike at the same 1000 Hertz ... also I suggest you feed your above input data into a DAW like audacity to plot out the FFT curve ... input your file -> highlight -> menu analyze -> plot spectrum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out signal data should be power of 2. It worked well.I used fft-js npm library